# Concurrency exclusion tuning

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

```
void method1() {
    if (is_true) {
        mutex1.lock();
        condition_var.wait(mutex1,
                              [=] { return is_true == false; });
        mutex1.unlock();
    }
    // do some work
}


void method2() {
    if (is_true) {
        mutex1.lock();
        condition_var.wait(mutex1,
                              [=] { return is_true == false; });
        mutex1.unlock();
    }
    // do some work
}

void method3() {
    mutex2.lock();
    is_true = true;
    // do some job
    mutex1.lock();
    is_true = false;
    condition_var.notify_all();
    mutex1.unlock();
    mutex2.unlock();
}
```

`method1` and `method2` can be executed concurrently and do not require to have any self synchronization, `method3` synchronize itself with `mutex2`. `method1`/`method2` cannot run concurrently with `method3` for this `condition_var` and `is_true` boolean are used as well as `mutex1`.
What I am concerned here that `mutex1` creates a zone of code where `method1` and `method2` are prevented from its concurrent behaviour. But I cannot remove this mutex because `is_true = false; condition_var.notify_all();` must be an atomic action.
How can I redesign it to remove locks from `method1` and `method2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your code. The conditional variable actually does not have a state. If you call `notify` before `wait`, it will wait infinitely. So you have to implement the state `is_true` manually and use a mutex to prevent race conditions.

You can also use event objects (`CreateEvent` for Windows, semaphores for Linux), but it will be less efficient. The implementation of `std::mutex` uses fast spinlocks, and makes slow system calls only after spinlock timeout. The guarded part of your code is short so the locks will not affect the performance.

Comment: Actually, nowhere is guaranteed that `std::mutex` is implemented via _futex_. So `std::mutex::lock()` is really expensive only when it is locked (because of blocking).